# Runtime error- POSIX threads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I am trying to create threads with the pthread library. Compilation is fine with 
    gcc -o -pthread file file.c

but when I run the code, I get a segmentation fault. I am not sure what the problem is. I tried to execute the code that was given in the textbook to try and learn but I am lost right now. Can anyone help? The code is below... very basic, yes but please hlep me out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int sum;
void *runner(void *param);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    //printf("Am I here..?\n");
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out ...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (atoi(argv[1] < 0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
        return -1;
    }



    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}

void *runner(void *param)
{
    extern int sum;
    int i, upper=atoi(param);
    sum=0;

    for(i=1; i<= upper; i++)
        sum+=i;

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It might be worth to learn how to use a debugger. On linux `gdb` would be the tools of choice. Having used `gdb` you would have found this error easily yourself in a quiet short time.

Comment: Also it is a good idea to compile using the option `-Wall` to turn on all warnings. In your specific case the warnings the compiler would print would have pointed you the critical line of code directly. Try it .. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Please turn on, and examine carefully, your compiler's warnings.

You're not including `stdlib.h`, so `atoi` is undeclared, and you're not `return`ing anything from `runner` but you've declared it as returning a `void*`.

But the main problem is this line:

```
if (atoi(argv[1] < 0))
```

`argv[1] < 0` will evaluate to `0` or `1`, which are not what you want as an argument to `atoi`. What you wanted is:

```
if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
```

It's more than likely that your compiler would have indicated all these problems if the right warnings were enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the bracket:

Change:

```
if (atoi(argv[1] < 0))
```

to:

```
if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it was something very silly...  would a debugger help me identify all little things like this?

Comment: Yes, they can help you identify which lines gives you segfault :)